# How can we zoom in image and draw rectangle over it as canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw rectangle over image and later send those rectangle top and left coordinates over rest api. I have a question that is it possible to zoom in image and get image pixels the same away?

```
   /* Drawing Image on canvas */
            function drawImageActualSize() {
                scope.canvasForImage.width = scope.image.naturalWidth;
                scope.canvas.width = scope.image.naturalWidth;
                scope.canvasForImage.height = scope.image.naturalHeight;
                scope.canvas.height = scope.image.naturalHeight + (scope.heightOfHeader.height);
                $('#canvas').css("top", `-${(scope.heightOfHeader.height)}`);
                scope.canvasForImageCtx.drawImage(scope.image, 0, 0);
            }

            /* Variables for free hand drawing rectangular boxes */
            scope.canvasx = $('#canvas').offset().left;
            scope.canvasy = $('#canvas').offset().top;
            scope.last_mousex, scope.last_mousey = 0;
            scope.mousex, scope.mousey = 0;
            scope.mousedown = false;
            scope.width, scope.height;
            scope.boundingBoxArray = [];
            scope.boundingBoxObject = {
                a: '',
                b: '',
                c: '',
                d: ''
            };
```

Comment: When you say image pixels, do you mean as a png / jpg. etc?.  If so, you can just create another canvas and draw your original image clipped to your rectangle.

Comment: @Keith Yes. Initially i am loading image (jpn/png)  image in canvas, then keeping another canvas over it for drawing rectangle

Comment: How are you zooming the image in canvas?

Comment: The easiest way to get the pixel data is to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL  This should work with your Rest API too, sometimes blob's can be more tricky when transmitting.  So in a nutshell, create another Canvas clipped using your rectangle and then save the pixel data with `toDataURL`.